# how to specify number of iterations in a lua pattern match attempt?

Tags: lua

I have the following lua code: (based on another post here on stackoverflow)

```
local chunks = {ip:match("(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)")}
if (#chunks == 4) then
    for _,v in pairs(chunks) do
        if (tonumber(v) < 0 or tonumber(v) > 255) then
            return false
        end
    end
    return true
else
    return false
end
```

Trouble with this logic for validating IPv4 Addresses is that when I test addresses like "1.2.3.4.5", the variable "chunks" still evaluates to 4.
How can I change this pattern so that it passes ONLY when there are exactly four octets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the anchor patterns `^` and `$` which mean "match at beginning of string" and "match at end of string" respectively at the beginning/end of your pattern to require the match capture the *entire* string:

```
local chunks = {ip:match("^(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)%.(%d+)$")}
```